# Connect to DocumentDB from another region

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, security, firewall, amazon-vpc

**TL;DR**

```
DocumentDB in another region <-------- ec2 instance in another region
                               access
```

So AWS has launched MongoDB as a service and calls it DocumentDB. 
Currently the supported regions are:
1. N. Virginia
2. Ohio
3. Oregon
4. Ireland

So according to their [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/getting-started.launch-ec2-instance.html), to access the documentDB:

> To interact with your Amazon DocumentDB cluster, you must launch an Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instance into your default VPC, in the same AWS Region where you created your Amazon DocumentDB cluster.

I did this and it works as expected.

The problem is, **how do I access this from another ec2 instance on another VPC, security group and another region.**

I tried to access it and this was the exception:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: .... 
[Errno 113] No route to host
```

Note: The above works if I launch an ec2 instance within the same region and same security group.

Is there something I can do to whitelist the ec2 instance in another region using firewall settings?

Comment: `No route to host` implies more things missing than just firewall settings (which should result in `Connection timed out`).  Are the VPCs peered?

Comment: You need a peering (VPC peering) connection between the VPCs and the routing table modified to route the DocumentDB request.

Comment: No the VPCs aren't peered... let me try that and get back

Comment: The following approach is mentioned in their docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect-from-outside-a-vpc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS documentdb troubleshooting guide [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/documentdb-cannot-connect/) answers this exact question;

I solved the same issue with **VPC Peering** (as described in the article)

Comment: curious what steps did you follow to setup VPC Peering?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [vpc-peer-region-example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-peer-region-example.html) documentation by AWS?

Seems like the architecture mentioned in ([doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-inter-region-peering-consumer-side.html)) is perfect fit for you. It shows how to use a combination of VPC peering and AWS PrivateLink to extend access to private services to consumer in different region (and different vpcs).

Answer (score 1):

Since **Document-DB cluster** and **DB-instance** are configured for a specific region by default, it can **only be accessed from the ec2-instances inside the VPC**.
or your local machine with access to PVC which is also in the same region.

**Note:** only if the security groups are enabled to access your machine IP.

However we can use port forward technique, aka **ssh tunneling** to enable any user from any region to access your DB, and it will still need an **ec2-instance** or **bastion instance** to be up and running.

Follow the document to create a proxy server using an amazon session manager
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/systems-manager-ssh-vpc-resources/

Create a tunnel from your machine

```
ssh -i  ec2-keypair-private.pem ec2-user-name@ec2-public-dns-name -N -L 27017:document-db-cluster-name:27017
```

Use Mongo shell to login to your machine locally

```
mongo --ssl --host localhost:27017 --sslCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --username username --password password
```

**Note:** Your Document-DB cluster should allow the ec2-instance you are using to access it, we can modify it from the security groups associated with that cluster.
Hope it helps!